# Problems with jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Ok, I've rolled my own theme, I've made a custom jQuery UI pack (progress bar, date picker, slider) and installed it all.  Seems to (mostly) work except for two things:

1. When my page first loads the datepicker div is visible; and
2. The text "Next" and "Prev" are visible in large font underneath my icons.  None of the examples seem to have this problem.

Now (1) I'm currently solving by:

```
#ui-datepicker-div { display: none; }
```

in another CSS file but again none of the demos seem to need this.

What am I missing?

Comment: Boot up firebug, highlight the buttons and find out what styles are being assigned. Then post them here, that should help us debug your problem.

Answer (score 7):

I fixed it using #ui-datepicker-div { display: none; }

Answer (score 5):

Ok many thanks, It's Work bro, here what I've did to resolve :
write this style to file jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css (or anye css file that you loaded) :

```
#ui-datepicker-div { display: none; }
```

then refresh your page

Answer (score 2):

1. make sure your javascript files are properly loaded, check for missing files or incorrect path.
2. make sure that your script run after the document is ready, try putting your script before  and/or inside the $(document).ready(){}
3. try stripping out your own css to see if there's any css conflict.
4. post some code for us here. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem because I was using the wrong version of the stylesheet for the version of jQuery UI I was using (I'd upgraded the jQuery UI without upgrading the stylesheet). If you're using jQuery UI 1.8.17, make sure that the stylesheet being used is also version 1.8.17.

Comment: I wonder why this question was dug out of the vault after nearly 3 years?

Comment: dunno, but we just had the same problem here

Comment: This also just started happening to me.  I rolled my own theme with the theme-roller and had this same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing nothing else about your problem, I believe it may be other css on your page conflicting with the picker.

Answer (score 1):

For me the css was not included (`jquery.ui.datepicker.css`). So I saw a div (`ui-datepicker-div`) at the bottom of the page and I got the following error with FireBug: `instActive is undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Please change from 
instActive.inline 
to 
(typeof(instActive) == 'undefined' || instActive.inline)

in your jqueryui.js

For discussion on this goto->http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datepicker/issues/detail?id=285

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered the second part of the question...

Add the following two lines to your .ui-icon CSS:

```
text-indent: -99999px;
overflow: hidden;
```

That should fix "Prev" and "Next" showing up.